# Why is [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] is nil after login in with permissions

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-login

When the fetchFacebookUserAndSurnameWith function is called, the access token parameter is nil.
That is after I've confirmed with the Facebook app on device. I think this means that the call is made after a successful login/authorization.

This is my code:

```
if(![FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]){
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc]init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email"]  fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error){
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"%@",error);

        }

        else{
            NSLog(@"------>TOKEN:%@",[[result token]tokenString]);
            NSArray *credentials =[self.nameSearchTextField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];



            [ws fetchFacebookUserAndSurnameWith:[credentials objectAtIndex:0] andSurname:[credentials objectAtIndex:1]andAceesToken:[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]tokenString]];

        }
    }];
}
```

My appDelegate looks like the following:

[image: MyAppDelegete ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone, browsing though this, I was using FSDKLoginButton as an instance variable in order to access it through different routines. That is why it wasn't working. You have to declare the button as google said.